# mysql quarter() function returns Jan-Mar as the first quarter. in india first quarter in Apr-Jun

Tags: mysql

My mysql query uses quarter() function to get the quarter in which a date falls in.
It returns the value as quarter 1 for months Jan-Mar. But I want it to return Jan-Mar as quarter 4. This is how quarter is defined in India where the fiscal year starts from April of a year to the March of the next year. Please advise.
Regards
Joseph

Comment: Simply speaking you have to store the quarters in another table and join them, there is no way to change this quarter (and by the by... even in India second quarter is Apr-Jun, calendar year is same always)

Comment: `quarter()` defines the quarter of the calendar year, not an arbitrary fiscal year.  Those of us in the US where some companies have fiscal years that start in April or July have the same issues to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid possibility of mistake and make the function behave exactly as you need, just write your own custom Quarter function. This way you can return result (quarter number) based on any date comparassing you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract 3 months from the date and then calculate the quarter.

```
select quarter(date_add(date'2013-01-01',interval -3 month));
```

This returns 4, as January is the fourth quarter in the financial year.

Comment: Would there be similar way to find out year(), month() and week(). I am worried whether the fix works for boundary dates, like '2013-03-30', '2013-03-31', '2013-04-01'. Also '2012-12-31', '2013-01-01'